# django template inheritance use same tag multiple templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am using the django template system fine-though is there a way to use the same variable inheritance tag for more than one template without pulling in the data from the other template too.

```
<div id="content-container3">

{% block content-container2 %}{% endblock %}

</div>
```

So I want to use the above in say *`people.html`* template and *`test.html`* template.

for example:
{% extends "base.html "}
{% block content-container2 %}{% endblock %}

Though it cross refernces information from two templates in this case -does each variable inheriatnce tag have to be unique?

Comment: Can you expand your question with example of template behaviour you expect?

Answer (score 0):

try to move this part of code to different file (content_container3.html) and use `include` tag... or I did not understand your question :)

Comment: Hi chmeliuk-The tag is included fine in both the base.html and the child template. Though I want to use the same tag in another child template and no surpise it crosses over the info from the other child template-So, I am sure there is a way round this, creating custom tags maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try nesting blocks like the below example.

```
{% block first_section %}
    {% block first_section_upper %}
      {{block.super}}
    {% endblock first_section_upper %}

      <h1 class="display-5">Some content</h1>
      <h5 style="color: white !important;" class="display-5"> *Your text here*</h5>

      <p class="lead">The Algorithms that run our Universe</p>

    {% block first_section_lower %}
      {{block.super}}
    {% endblock first_section_lower %}
{% endblock first_section %}
```

The h1 tag and p tags can be different for every new template. As far as i could understand, this might solve your problem.